# Running a cron job with limited ability to change the path

Tags: php, path, cron

I've just opened a free hosting account with Hostinger UK. For a free account, it gives plenty of functionality, including the ability to run a cron job. However, the control panel is already set up with path: `/usr/bin/wget http://example.com/` and this is set in stone. All I can add is the rest of the path to the php file I want to run, e.g. `sub-dir/myfile.php`.

Unfortunately, the file is never run for some reason, and the cron log file never gets created, so I can't see if there's any clues in it. The cron job is set up to run every hour, and can be run manually, but neither work.

Can any of you guys point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very environment-specific question. You should really take this up with Hostinger's support desk.

Comment: Hi OldskoolYes, I realise that, and I have already spoken to Hostinger, who say I would have to upgrade to a premium account to gain more control. They couldn't or wouldn't say why my path won't work.

Comment: you can check, cron is running or not. You can parse the output of `crontab -l` to see if a particular crontab entry is present or not. As for if `cron` is running or not, you can parse the output of a `ps -eaf` command to see if `crond` is running or not.

Comment: Thanks yahoo, but I don't have that kind of access. I suppose my question is: Should the path '/usr/bin/wget http://example.com/sub-dir/myfile.php' actually work. The sub-dir and myfile definitely exist.